# MapKit resets to users current location

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, mapkit

I have a strange problem with MapKit.
I have a map view with my annotations and when a user clicks on the pin, I push a detail view controller of the pin

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[ImagePin class]])
    {
        if (!self.pinPhotoDetailViewController) {
            self.pinPhotoDetailViewController = [[PinPhotoDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PinPhotoDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        }
        self.pinPhotoDetailViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
        self.pinPhotoDetailViewController.photoID = view.annotation.title;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.pinPhotoDetailViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I pop back to the map, it has changed the region and now shows the region of users current location.
I init the map view with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeNone;

    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:80.0f];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    firstLaunch=YES;
    [self customizeStyle];

}
```

Where am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are you doing something MapView related stuff in viewDidUnload or viewWillDisapear? if yes please share that also because code you shared seems good.

Comment: @suraj No nothing...i haven't implemented this method...

Comment: Please try one thing, not so sure about that but...
implement viewWillAppear  and put self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeNone.

Comment: This question is missing critical code from the author implementation of `viewDidAppear:`.